# Handling exception from unparsable input into JSON.parse()

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I came across this issue while creating a way to manage cookies in JS. My cookies can contain strings that are in JSON format:

```
var cookieContents = '{"type":"cookie","isLie":true}';
```

... or that are just plain strings:

```
var cookieContents = 'The cookie is a lie';
```

To parse the cookie, I would ideally do `JSON.parse(cookieContents)`. The problem with this is `JSON.parse()` cannot parse a plain string and throws a fatal error.

My question is **what is the best/most widely accepted way to handle a situation like this?**

I have tried using a try/catch statement:

```
var cookie1 = '{"type":"cookie","isLie":true}';
var cookie2 = 'The cookie is a lie';

function parseCookieString(str){
    var output;

    try{
        output = JSON.parse(str);
    } catch(e){
        output = str;
    }

    console.log(output);
}

parseCookieString(cookie1); // outputs object
parseCookieString(cookie2); // outputs string
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fmpeyton/7w60cesp/

This works perfectly fine, but feels dirty. Maybe because I usually do not handle JS fatal errors. **Is it very common to handle fatal errors more gracefully in a scenario like this?**

Comment: this is actually a design error in `JSON.parse()` (oh! a design error in JavaScript! So rare! ohwait...) -> this shan't be a fatal error, it should return `null` or something. Or it should have a method that only checks validity (like `JSON.isValid()`, this would probably be the cleanest solution.)

Answer (score 0):

Doing a try catch makes sense but if `JSON.parse` throws an error because of something else than your `output` variable could end up containing something that you did not intend.

That's an interesting problem though. I would do something like this - basically checking for the presence of `{` and `}` in the string:

```
function parseCookieString(str){
    var output;

    if (!!str.match(/^{.+}$/)) {
      output = JSON.parse(str);
    } else {
      output = str;
    }

    console.log(output);
}

parseCookieString(cookie1); // outputs object
parseCookieString(cookie2); // outputs string
```

Comment: the fact that the string is wrapped inside curly braces does not make it valid JSON.

Comment: Not sure that the concern was invalid JSON. Basically he provided 2 options: Valid JSON in data or Valid String in data. The solution above solves that exact problem... makes sense?

Comment: What if he has `"{The cookie is a lie.}"`?

Comment: That's invalid JSON, which is exactly what the OP was not concerned about.

Comment: Might as well let's also worry that he might have: `"The cookie is a lie.`